# Is there an online copy of English translation of Pramanavarttika of Shri Dharmakirthi?

Tags: books

Is there a an online copy of English translation of Pramanavarttika of Shri Dharmakirthi?

Of the available links only second chapter is available.

If the full version is available, please provide the link for it.

Comment: Can down voters please say why you are downvoting. So that if there's something I can fix, I will fix it.

Comment: Maybe it is because you aspirated the T in "Dharmakīrti?" Who knows? It's a fine question, so it's back to 0 from -1 now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, there are quite a few trasnlations available in ENglish, by reputed scholars of the field. The book has a total of five chapters. SOme works cover individual chapters like Tom J.F. Tilleman's translation, which is of the fourth chapter or Nagatomi's PhD disstertation which is a translation work of the first chapter. Another scholar by the name of John D. Dunne has some parts translated, in his book titiled *Foundations of Dharmakirti's Philosophy*. There is a translation by Mookerjee and Nagasaki. There is an e-text by MOtoi Ono. Then there are some translations that include the commentary. But to be able to access good translations, you would very likely need UNiversity access or individual subscriptions. Books are more easily available.

Edit: You may find the following link useful.
https://east.ikga.oeaw.ac.at/buddh/ind/7/16/

Answer (score 0):

Here is a chapter.

I didn't see any full translations, but you can find bits like this, also like the second chapter you found.

https://www.academia.edu/30822030/Dharmakirtis_Pramanavarttika_An_annotated_translation_of_the_fourth_chapter_Vol_1_k_1_148_

Comment: I'm especially looking for the first chapter which is just not foubd anywhere.

Comment: The formatting is absolutely terrible on this old document, but I also found this: https://archive.org/stream/AStudyOfDharmakirtisPramanavarttikaMasatoshiNagatomi/A%20study%20of%20Dharmakirti%27s%20Pramanavarttika_%20-%20Masatoshi%20Nagatomi_djvu.txt

Comment: even in this the first chapter seems to be missing and onlysecond chaptee is present. I'm trying to find Dharmakirti's refutation of authorlessness and authority of Vedas. I cant find it. Its supposed to be there in the first chapter. I can't find it in the link you have given.

Comment: On this page here, https://east.ikga.oeaw.ac.at/buddh/ind/7/16/, you'll see "Mookerjee, Satkari, and Hojun Nagasaki. 1964. The Pramāṇavārttikam of Dharmakīrti: An English Translation of the First Chapter with the Autocommentary and with Elaborate Comments. Nava Nālandā Mahāvihāra Research Publication 4. Patna: Nava Nālandā Mahāvihāra."

Comment: If you can track that down, hopefully it would be the whole first chapter.

Comment: thanks for the amazing work. I know about this book. But this book is copyright protected and is not available online.

Comment: Have you tried looking in the library catalogs of nearby universities?

Comment: I'm in a country where the nearest university library which has this book is in a different country.